# Plot surface where Z depends on a vector of X and Y

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm currently working on a small python script which can be used to interpolate points with  a radial basis function approach. Therefore I would like to plot a surface where the Z value is calculated by a vector which depends on X and Y.

The formula I need to implement looks like this:
[image]

My current approach is the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def phi(x):
    return np.exp(- np.power(x, 2))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

x = np.arange(0, 6, 0.25)
y = np.arange(0, 6, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = 0.49 * phi(np.linalg.norm(np.array([[1,1], [X,Y]]))) + \
    0.79 * phi(np.linalg.norm(np.array([[2,3], [X,Y]]))) + \
    0.39 * phi(np.linalg.norm(np.array([[4,2], [X,Y]])))

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='viridis')

plt.xlim(0, 6)
plt.ylim(0, 6)
plt.show()
```

Something seems to be wrong with the parameter that I pass to the phi()-function but I'm not sure what it is.
So how can I calculate the Z value correctly?

Note: I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47553958/3d-surface-plot-where-z-is-a-function-that-takes-a-vector-formed-from-x-and-y), but the answer did not help me in my case.

Comment: (1,1)^T - x is a vector of coordinates (1-X, 1-Y) (where X,Y are the coordinates of vector x). Because it's only a length 2 vector, you can compute the norm with the pythagorean formula which makes it easier to "vectorize" the calculation. `np.sqrt((1-X)**2+(1-Y)**2)` should do the trick

Comment: For your information, here you're computing the norm of a 2x2 matrix of coordinates [[1,1],[X,Y]] which is not what is asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mateo Vial mentioned in the comments, the simplest approach is to calculate the norm with the pythagorean formula. The working code looks like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def phi(x):
    return np.exp(- np.power(x, 2))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

x = np.arange(0, 6, 0.25)
y = np.arange(0, 6, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = 0.49 * phi(np.sqrt((1-X)**2+(1-Y)**2)) + \
    0.79 * phi(np.sqrt((2-X)**2+(3-Y)**2)) + \
    0.39 * phi(np.sqrt((4-X)**2+(2-Y)**2))

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='viridis')

plt.xlim(0, 6)
plt.ylim(0, 6)
plt.show()
```

And now the result is a good interpolation with a radial basis function.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to refactor what you have:

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def phi(x):
    return np.exp(-np.power(x, 2))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 7))

x = y = np.arange(0, 6, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
xy = np.stack([X.flat, Y.flat]).T

Z = (0.49 * phi(la.norm(np.array([[1, 1]]) - xy, axis=1)) +
     0.79 * phi(la.norm(np.array([[2, 3]]) - xy, axis=1)) +
     0.39 * phi(la.norm(np.array([[4, 2]]) - xy, axis=1))
    )

surf = ax.imshow(Z.reshape(X.shape))
plt.show()
```

This produces:

[image: The output grid as a map]